# Improved Selection Sort Out of Bounds Error

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a method that is an "Improved version of Selection Sort". However, the code is not running as " temp[x] = 0;" this line gives an out of bounds of the array error. I do not want to use an ArrayList. How would I change this line to be in bounds of the array?

```
    public static void ImprovedSelectionSort(int[] Array)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        int[] temp = new int[Array.Length];
        for (int x = 1; x <= Array.Length; x++)
        {
            //OtherList.Add(0); -- what I want to do
            temp[x] = 0;
        }

        int n = Array.Length;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n)
        {
            int rear = 0; 
            int curMax = Array[i]; 
           temp[rear] = i; 
            int j = i + 1;

            while (j < n)
            {
                if (curMax < Array[j])
                {
                    curMax = Array[j];
                    rear = -1;
                }
                if (curMax == Array[j])
                {
                    rear = rear + 1;
                    temp[rear] = j;
                }
                j++;
            }
            int front = 0;
            int p = Array[temp[front]];
            while (front <= rear)
            {
                int temporary = p;
                Array[temp[front]] = Array[i];
                Array[i] = temporary;
                i++;
                front += 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `for (int x = 1; x <= Array.Length; x++) {temp[x] = 0;}` - arrays in C# are *zero-based*, you probably want `for (int x = 0; x < Array.Length; x++) {temp[x] = 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

> for (int x = 1; x <= Array.Length; x++)

This is most likely the issue. The last index in an array is the length minus 1 (so, a 52-card deck goes from 0..51). Changing the "x <= Array.Length" component to "x < Array.Length" should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the <= to < in the for loop. This is a common mistake among novice devs, and not something you should sweat. But it's a good thing to keep in mind for the future.